# Spring Security 3: hasRole rules are separately checked or?

Tags: spring, spring-security, urlaccess

I have this case in my project:

Imagine we have these two lines to define Spring Security access rules:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/xxx/*" access="isAuthenticated() and (hasRole('roleA') or hasRole('roleB'))" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/xxx/yyy*" access="isAuthenticated() and (hasRole('role1') or hasRole('role2'))" />
```

These two patterns are nested, and an user may have a combination of roles like "roleA" and "role1", or "roleA" and "role2". What I want to achieve, is make users have "roleC" and "role1" cannot access to `/xxx/yyy*`.

So my question is:

When user with "roleC" and "role1" wants to get access with pattern "xxx/yyy222.html", will all lines of access rule be checked, or only the second line is checked? When considering the access rules for the second line, can I take it for granted that user can get into the url "xxx/yyy*" have only "roleA" and "roleB", or must I put complete rules for each single lines of rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `intercept-url`s are processed in the order they are defined, the first with a pattern that matches the request path decides the access.

> When user with "roleC" and "role1" wants to get access with pattern
>   "xxx/yyy222.html", will all lines of access rule be checked, or only
>   the second line is checked?

This matches the pattern of the first line and access will be denied.

> When considering the access rules for the second line, can I take it
>   for granted that user can get into the url "xxx/yyy*" have only
>   "roleA" and "roleB", or must I put complete rules for each single
>   lines of rule?

The second line will never be evaluated. Be sure to specify more specific pattern first.

> What I want to achieve, is make users have "roleC" and "role1" cannot
>   access to /xxx/yyy*.

Maybe you want something like:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/xxx/yyy*" access="isAuthenticated() and !(hasRole('roleC') and hasRole('role1'))" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I am also checking other answers and get doc reference. Accepted as the first and correct one.